# Superset Excel Export Numeric Values Alignment

Tags: apache-superset

Is there a way to have numeric values right aligned while exporting a chart as excel in superset, currently it's aligning all the values to the left converting all the values to text.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fj1Yk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvSJv.png)

Thanks in Advance!!

expected result - Numeric values aligned left

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTqa8.png)